# Spring Batch CSV conversion

Tags: spring-batch, export-to-csv

I am working on txt file to csv conversion in spring Batch, a am using pipe seperated text file and my problem is when i try to write into csv if a field encounters comma a new field is created in csv, i.e if i have address like |Mumbai,India| in text file it creates two fields i.e Mumbai and India in CSV file instead it should write Mumbai,India as single field.

CSV ItemWriter

```
<bean id="ABCWriters" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:output/ABC.csv"></property>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"></property>

    <property name="lineAggregator">    
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=","></property>

            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                  <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="address, city" />
                   </bean>
            </property>         
        </bean>          
    </property>             
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to extend the `DelimitedLineAggregator` and wrap each field that contains a `,` to be surrounded in double-quotes `"`. Additionally, for any field that contains a comma AND a double-qoute, you'll want to escape each double-quote with another double-quote like so:

```
some value          -> some value
some, value         -> "some, value"
some, "other" value -> "some, ""other"" value"
```

FYI: this is how Excel handles CSV documents

Comment: Better explanation, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me before, Try to surround it with Double Quotes
Example :

```
new_content = "\"" + review_content.text() + "\"";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for quick reply, actually i am new to spring Batch, can you tell me where exactly i need to do changes in my code or could you suggest some example to refer.

Comment: I cant say much with out having a look into your back-end of the project. Just forget about the spring part.The problem lies in the CSV process. Just go the code line where you get the string value which is going to save as a CSV .Before save it to the CSV just change it's content by adding Double Quotes @ the begining and end as I mentioned above. Im sure it will work .Refer: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2458888/spring-framework/open-source-java-projects-spring-batch.html